# The Image of normal subgroup is also normal subgroup?

Tags: normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be a group , $N\lhd G$ ,

$ \varphi:G\rightarrow G'$ is homomorphism onto $G'$,

prove that $\varphi(N)=\{\varphi(n):n\in N\}$ is normal subgroup of $G'$

Comment: You need $\phi$ to be surjective.

Comment: You have to move them together. Normality is a relation between two. So $A\lhd B$ implies $\phi(A)\lhd \phi(B)$ and $\psi^{-1}(A)\lhd \psi^{-1}(B)$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof that this is a normal subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013797/proof-that-this-is-a-normal-subgroup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\phi(n)\in\phi(N)$.  Let $a\in G'$.  Then $\exists$ $g\in G$ such that $\phi(g)=a$.  Then $a\phi(n)a^{-1}=\phi(g)\phi(n)\phi(g)^{-1}=\phi(gng^{-1})\in\phi(N)$ because $gng^{-1}\in N$ because $N$ is normal.  QED.